# The laptop does not scan my Wi-Fi network

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, internet-connection, wifi-configuration, acer-aspire

I have an **Acer Aspire A315-21** laptop and he does not scan my Wi-Fi. He scans the Wi-Fi network from the entire building except for my Wi-Fi. I thought that the problem is the OS (**Endless**), so I change it with Linux Mint, but the problem persists. Also, I can connect the laptop to wire and to mobile hotspot connection. If you have some idea, please write back.

Comment: Is your wireless network 2.4 GHz, 5 GHz or both? Can your phone or any other device see your WiFi?

Comment: The wireless network is 2.4 GHz and yes other devices can see my Wi-Fi.

Comment: Does it connects to your net while inserting its parameters manually? Does your net is NOT set as hidden?

Comment: No, he does not connect when I insert manually the parameters and the net is not hidden.

Comment: What model is your router?

Comment: It's Edimax, 6 years old, but I don't know the exact model.

Answer (score 0):

Need to update the Firmware. For Edimax router model: BR-6428nS you can download the file from [here](https://www.edimax.com/edimax/download/download/data/edimax/global/download/). Then acces the router settings, go to option *Tools* from menu and click to **Firmware Upgrade**. Press **Next** and then press **Browse** to select the file who was download. Press **Apply** ti finish the action. A few minutes the network will not work. And then rescan for wireless connection.

Comment: It's not a driver issue. How would a laptop driver problem cause a laptop to *consistently* be unable to detect certain access points? And how would it affect two different operating systems, each with different drivers? He's experiencing the same exceptionally rare problem with two completely different drivers already.

Comment: @wrecclesham The answer mentions *firmware* update for the **router**.

Comment: Oh I see now. That's definitely worth a shot. In that case, try to update the router's firmware first, then try my answer if the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `Channel Width` setting on your Edimax router.

This screenshot may be for a different model, so the options you see may be a little different, including the channel width combinations offered:

[image]

Certain wireless devices are unable to use the wider 40 MHz channel width. This limitation can render networks that do not offer 20 MHz as a fallback as completely invisible to affected client devices.

I [read](https://www.smallnetbuilder.com/wireless/wireless-reviews/32219-edimax-br-6478ac-ac1200-wireless-concurrent-dual-band-gigabit-router-reviewed?start=4) that some Edimax routers fail the "Fat Channel intolerant test". This means that, when a client device is unable to use the "fat" 40 GHz channel because their radio's hardware doesn't support it, and requests that the router communicates on the "thin" 20 MHz band, the router refuses to switch to 20 MHz, even if it is *supposed* to automatically choose between 20/40 MHz.

What I believe is happening here is a combination of your laptop's inability to use any channel width greater than 20 MHz, combined with your router behaving out of specification and refusing to provide 20 MHz when in 20/40 MHz mode. Another possibility is that the router was changed to 40 MHz mode at some point; however, this is not the default setting and so is less likely.

Try changing your router's channel width to 20 MHz *only* and see if your laptop suddenly starts being able to detect your wireless network!